# How to solve this differential equation analytically?

Tags: differential-equations

[image: See the image.]How can I `DSolve` the following differential equation?
Is there an analytical answer to this equation?

```
DSolve[(1/(G*L*(n - r)*(n + r)))*Sin[θ1]*Sin[θ2]*
       (54*(n^2 - r^2)^6 + 2*L^2*(9*r^4*(9*q0^2 + 2*r^6) + 
               36*n^6*r^4*(-5 + 4*V0^2) - 
               18*n^10*(1 + 4*V0^2) + 18*n^8*r^2*
                 (5 + 16*V0^2) - 2*n^2*(9*q0^2*r^2 + 
                    96*q0*r^5*V0 + r^8*(45 + 4*V0^2)) + 
               n^4*(9*q0^2 - 192*q0*r^3*V0 + 
                    20*r^6*(9 + 8*V0^2))) + 
          9*L^2*(12*L^4*m*(14*n^6 - 51*n^4*r^2 + 5*r^6)*
                 V[r]^3 + (n - r)^3*(n + r)^3*Derivative[1][V][
                   r]*(4*r*(n^2 - r^2)^2 + 3*L^4*m*
                      Derivative[1][V][r]*(n^2 + r^2 + 
                         (3*n^2*r + r^3)*Derivative[1][V][r])) + 
               6*L^4*m*(n - r)*(n + r)*V[r]^2*
                 (12*n^2*r*(-5*n^2 + r^2)*Derivative[1][V][r] + 
                    (n - r)*(n + r)*(10*n^2 - 6*r^2 - 
                         6*(n^4 - n^2*r^2 + 2*r^4)*Derivative[2][V][
                             r] + 3*(n - r)*r*(n + r)*(2*n^2 + r^2)*
                           Derivative[3][V][r])) - (n - r)^2*(n + r)^2*
                 V[r]*(4*(n^6 + (-3*L^4*m + n^4)*r^2 - 
                         5*n^2*r^4 + 3*r^6) + 3*L^4*m*
                      (-36*n^2*r^2*Derivative[1][V][r]^2 + 
                         (n - r)*(n + r)*(2*(n^2 + 4*r^2)*
                                Derivative[2][V][r] + 3*r^2*(-n + r)*
                                (n + r)*Derivative[2][V][r]^2 + 
                              2*r*(-n + r)*(n + r)*Derivative[3][V][
                                  r]) + 3*r*Derivative[1][V][r]*
                           (8*n^2 - 2*(4*n^4 - 5*n^2*r^2 + r^4)*
                                Derivative[2][V][r] - r*(n^2 - r^2)^2*
                                Derivative[3][V][r]))))) == 0, 
 V[r], r]
```

Comment: Your code dosen't work for me. Check syntax.When Mathematica returns the input as the output, it means that the calculation returned unevaluated. This often means that the function does not have the methods available to solve the problem symbolically, or it is mathematically impossible to obtain a symbolic solution (not all sums, integrals, or differential equations have symbolic solutions after all).

Comment: What about starting with a simpler equation and a correct MA syntax? Your present code does not represent a valid MA expression.

Comment: For me, it is ok in any version! I will attach an image too.

Comment: With your updated's code give me an error `DSolve::dvnoarg: The function V appears with no arguments.` ?.Maybe you can try: `DSolve[eq // InputForm, V[r], r]` and then copy/paste ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk : It's edited now.

Comment: @PerfectFluid Any reason to expect an analytic closed-form solution exists? Equations do not, in general, have "simple" solutions. Numeric methods are all we can do, usually.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : Actually I have no idea about existing the analytical solution! However, I hope so. It could be very nice to have an integrated form (one time) too.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started: it is not the full solution, though...
Let us denote your equation as `eq`. Then for a partial case of $m=0$, there is a nice analytic solution

```
DSolve[Simplify[eq/.{m->0}],V[r],r]
Out[1]= {{V[r]->(1/(90 L^2 (-n^2+r^2)^2))
           (27 (5 n^6+15 n^4 r^2-5 n^2 r^4+r^6)-(1/((n^2-r^2)^2))5 L^2 
           (27 q0^2 r^2-6 r^8-72 n^6 r^2 V0^2+60 n^4 r^4 (-1+2 V0^2)
           +18 n^8 (1+4 V0^2)+n^2 (-9 q0^2-96 q0 r^3 V0+8 r^6 (6+V0^2))))
           +(r C[1])/(-n^2+r^2)^2}}
```

Comment: Tank you, but actually this is not the case. The most important part of this problem  is `m` and it should be survived.

Comment: @PerfectFluid If other parameters are sufficiently small it might be worth it to try [`AsymptoticDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolve.html), otherwise you are probably better off with a numeric solution.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke No, I want the general solution. It seems that this is not possible.