# How to integrate this expression one time?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

How can I integrate this expression? I want to have the second derivative of `V` i.e. `V''[r]`. Note that, you can multiply it be any suitable expression you want. Note that, `n` is a (constant) model parameter. I have brought a 4D sample. The problem is the 6D case (see below).
Can you help me? Why `a2` has an answer but `a1` not?!

Note that, [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202059/how-to-solve-this-differential-equation-analytically) I've asked a question to find the analytic answer of such a case. However, it seems that there are no such solutions. So to avoid any ambiguity (or duplication) I want to emphasis that, here my question is in relation with the once integration (not to DSolving).

```
em6D=(-3*(n^2 - r^2))/L^2 + (2*(n^2 + 3*r^2)*V[r])/(n^2 - r^2) - 
 2*r*Derivative[1][V][r] + 
 m*((-6*L^4*(14*n^6 - 51*n^4*r^2 + 5*r^6)*V[r]^3)/(n^2 - r^2)^5 - 
   (3*L^4*r*(3*n^2 + r^2)*Derivative[1][V][r]^3)/(2*(n^2 - r^2)^2) + 
   V[r]^2*((-36*L^4*n^2*r*(-5*n^2 + r^2)*Derivative[1][V][r])/
      (n^2 - r^2)^4 + (18*L^4*(n^4 - n^2*r^2 + 2*r^4)*
       Derivative[2][V][r])/(n^2 - r^2)^3 - 
     (9*L^4*r*(2*n^2 + r^2)*Derivative[3][V][r])/(n^2 - r^2)^2) + 
   V[r]*((-54*L^4*n^2*r^2*Derivative[1][V][r]^2)/(n^2 - r^2)^3 - 
     (9*L^4*r^2*Derivative[2][V][r]^2)/(2*n^2 - 2*r^2) + 
     Derivative[1][V][r]*((9*L^4*r*(-4*n^2 + r^2)*Derivative[2][V][r])/
        (n^2 - r^2)^2 - (9*L^4*r^2*Derivative[3][V][r])/
        (2*n^2 - 2*r^2))))
```

```
em4D=(-6*(n - r)*(n + r))/L^2 + (2*(n^2 + r^2)*V[r])/((n - r)*(n + r)) - 
 2*r*Derivative[1][V][r] + 
 m*((6*L^4*(n^6 - 16*n^4*r^2 - 45*n^2*r^4)*V[r]^3)/(n^2 - r^2)^5 - 
   (3*L^4*n^2*r*Derivative[1][V][r]^3)/(n^2 - r^2)^2 + 
   V[r]^2*((-6*L^4*(3*n^4*r + 62*n^2*r^3 + r^5)*Derivative[1][V][r])/
      (n^2 - r^2)^4 + (6*L^4*(2*n^4 - 15*n^2*r^2 - r^4)*
       Derivative[2][V][r])/(n^2 - r^2)^3 - 
     (3*L^4*r*(4*n^2 + r^2)*Derivative[3][V][r])/(n^2 - r^2)^2) + 
   V[r]*((3*L^4*(n^4 - 37*n^2*r^2 - 2*r^4)*Derivative[1][V][r]^2)/
      (n^2 - r^2)^3 - (3*L^4*r^2*Derivative[2][V][r]^2)/
      (2*n^2 - 2*r^2) + Derivative[1][V][r]*
      ((-6*L^4*r*(5*n^2 + r^2)*Derivative[2][V][r])/(n^2 - r^2)^2 - 
       (3*L^4*r^2*Derivative[3][V][r])/(2*n^2 - 2*r^2))))
```

```
a1=Integrate[(1 - n^2/r^2) em6D, r]
a2=Integrate[(1 - n^2/r^2) em4D, r]
```

Comment: `How can I integrate this equation?` this is not an equation. An equation has a `==` in it. It will help if you also show what you tried. For example, the `Integrate` command you tried.

Comment: You try to "Integrate" a third order differential equation???   What do you expect from the result?

Comment: Dear @UlrichNeumann maybe something is wrong. How should I find `V''[r]` using `eq`? I think it is possible to multiply the `eq` by something and then make a total derivative. Is it true?

Comment: @Perfect Fluid  Ok perhaps I got it. Try to solve your equation for `V'''[r]` and multiply the result by `V''[r]` . This gives `V''[r] V'''[r] =1/2D[V''[r]^2,r]` which you can try to integrate. But you have to integrate a complex rational function depending on `r, V[r],V'[r],...`. Don't know wether it's possible.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I just checked your idea. It doesn't work out. In fact, after calculating `V'''[r]` from solving the equation, Mathematica couldn't calculate the integration of `V''[r] V'''[r]`.